# change discord.py bot status

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

it may hard to me, but i believe on stackoverflow power,

i need to put a number as bot status on my bot.

Here : http://gamers-control-2.000webhostapp.com/count.txt

Also Pic of it : [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43gO8.png)

> *#time to show status = text that founded in blank website = "41"*
>
> **#http://gamers-control-2.000webhostapp.com/count.txt**
>
> **#some how, you say i can type the number, i say the number in web it 
>   change everytime,   so i need to get that number to show it as bot status.**

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time
import random
from discord import Game


Client = discord.client
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
Clientdiscord = discord.Client()




@client.event
async def on_ready():

 await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name=http://gamers-control-2.000webhostapp.com/count.txt, type=3))

 print('test ready')

client.run("....")
```

im new with discord.py

Comment: The problem you're having isn't clear. Something to note is that you need to wrap the url in quotes in the `name=` attribute in the `discord.Game()` call.

Comment: for that i dont know how to get that text value to be (bot status) = count.txt (text inside)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first import requests at the beginning

```
import requests
```

Then before the ready event

```
count = requests.get('http://gamers-control-2.000webhostapp.com/count.txt')
```

And then you set it to

```
await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name=count.text, type=3))
```

Comment: Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hema\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hema\Desktop\GC_Bot.py", line 25, in on_ready
    await client.change_presence(activity=Game(name=count.text))
TypeError: change_presence() got an unexpected keyword argument 'activity'

Comment: My response didn't take into account you not using the rewrite branch. I've edited the response to be more correct. Please try it now

Comment: Work, You Are the best

Answer (score 0):

I use `await bot.change_presence()` like this:

**NOTICE:**

I am leaving out part of my code

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    replit.clear()
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name} - {bot.user.id}')
    bot.remove_command('help')
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game("mod help"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i use

````
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {bot.user}')
    print('Ready!')
    return await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=3, name='Add status here'))```
````

Comment: 1 = Playing, 2 = Listening, 3 = Watching